# Jest test suite failed to run AngularJS v1.x is not loaded! after upgrade angular 7 to 9

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular8, angular9, ts-jest

I am getting the below error when i run **npm test**  we have used jest for unit test coverage.

Test suite failed to run
AngularJS v1.x is not loaded!

```
  at Object.noNg (../../../packages/upgrade/src/common/src/angular1.ts:228:9)
  at node_modules/@uirouter/angular-hybrid/bundles/ng:/@uirouter/angular-hybrid/angular-hybrid.ts:51:38
  at node_modules/@uirouter/angular-hybrid/bundles/uirouter-angular-hybrid.umd.js:2:68
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@uirouter/angular-hybrid/bundles/uirouter-angular-hybrid.umd.js:5:2)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/customer-forms/customer-forms.routing.module.ts:2:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/customer-forms/index.ts:6:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/core/effects/library.effects.ts:25:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/core/effects/index.ts:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/core/index.ts:41:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/selectors/print-queue.selectors.ts:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/selectors/index.ts:7:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/shared/directives/order-by.directive.ts:13:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/shared/directives/index.ts:2:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/shared/shared.module.ts:4:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/shared/index.ts:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test/effects/common.effects.test.ts:4:1)
```

Any one has idea on this please help.

It has both angulajs and angular9 upgrade code base

Jest configuration

```
"@types/jest": "24.0.6",
"bamboo-jest-reporter": "1.0.3",
"jest": "24.9.0",
"jest-junit": "10.0.0",
"ts-jest": "24.1.0"
```

The above versions are listed in package.json. it is working in angularjs+angular7 solution after upgrade to 9 or 10 versions i am getting the above mentioned issue.

Comment: is `Test suite failed to run AngularJS v1.x is not loaded!` part of error message shown? is you code based on angularJs or angular2+ or both? what runner/plugins do you use for `jest`/`angular` integration?

Comment: yes it has both, with more details i have updated the query

Comment: Hi skyboyer you have any suggestions regarding this issue

Comment: no, unfortunately, have never worked with mix of angularjs+angular, probably, there may be some unique issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got fixed
This issue is coming because of the paths of the services imports. We have imported service directly from the paths like bellow

```
import { WorkPermitsService } from '../../work-permits/work-permits.service';
```

After upgrading to angular 9 imported paths are not resolved when I run the unit tests. So i have exported it in services index.ts and importing from @services (common place for exporting) where ever required. like this i have done for all.

Change :

```
export { WorkPermitsService } from '../../work-permits/work-permits.service';
```

Importing in required places

```
import { WorkPermitsService} from '@services';
```